# How to create Restful api for mobile app in laravel 5.2

Tags: json, laravel-5

I'm creating an api for a mobile app in laravel version 5.2, but I don't have any idea how to return exception in JSON format. I've been doing api development and tested using chrome postman.

Please help me how can I start with laravel 5.2?

I can't understand how to set error response in laravel 5.2.
I've already tried below plugin, but still didn't succeed:

1. json-api with laravel,
2. dingo/api, it's work with laravel 4

How can we do authentication in laravel 5.2 from mobile app?

Something good references and video link so I can learn and development in laravel 5.2 very friendly.

Comment: read in the docs about json response: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#json-responses

Comment: If you want to do authentication you can use this [package](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)

Comment: Check out Laracasts if you're looking for a good Laravel resource to learn from. Here's a link to one of their API series: https://laracasts.com/series/incremental-api-development

Answer (score 5):

For the creation of Restful API using Laravel 5.2 you could use below mention Laravel API generator Package .

https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator

As well as for the Authentication based on Token you could refer below mention Link.

https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51

One more additional thing if you have already created database / system and wants to use that for the creation of API using Laravel Generator package than use below mention command.

> php artisan infyom:api_scaffold Packages --fromTable
>   --tableName=packages

Hope this information will help you to create complete Restful API using Laravel 5.2

Comment: Complete Information about API for Mobile APP using Laravel 5.2 is mention at this post 

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/api-mobile-app-using-laravel-52-nayan-jogi

Answer (score 2):

I am also creating a Web Based Application for Android using Laravel 5.2 and we are using Rest API for this process. We are using API Guard for the purpose of Authentication. It works Perfect for us. We are authenticating it for Android as well as AngularJS and works fine for us. https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard. A Clear Documentation is Provided here. Hope so you have got your doubt cleared using this.

Comment: Give any references for error handling response in json format cause it's still viewing html format. If any route not find in my **route.php**, It'll be return error exception in html page view. I need to solution in json format....everything..so it's done restful api....

Comment: Post you Code where your Error Message is Displayed From the Controller.

Comment: Are you using redirect to view for error Message display.

Comment: [Api-response package](https://github.com/ellipsesynergie/api-response) using api for response but not install in my laravel package 5.2. Suppose i don't have any routes in **route.php**, How can I return error in json format

Comment: You can Install APIGuard as per my Suggestion it is best and very easy. You can return the Error Message in json with the help of this command [ return $this->response->errorNotFound(); ]
It will automatically print your Error Message as Json Format.

Comment: thanks i was looking for a way to authenticate users in Angular as well as android, it should be a nice package!